# Determining odd and even number of an array (pre-defined array) and storing them into 2 Separate Arrays

Tags: c, arrays

Hi my i am trying to Determining odd and even number of an array(pre-defined array) and storing them  into 2 Separate Arrays but there is some problem. its not showing the correct result. See here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main()
{
long int ARR[10]={2,5,4,7,8,0,9};
long int OAR[10], EAR[10];
int i, j = 0, k = 0, n;


for (i = 0; i <ARR[i]; i++)
{
    if (ARR[i] % 2 == 0)
    {
        EAR[j] = ARR[i];
        j++;
    }
    else
    {
        OAR[k] = ARR[i];
        k++;
    }
}

printf("The elements of OAR are \n");
for (i = 0; i < j; i++)
{
    printf("%ld\n", OAR[i]);
}
printf("The elements of EAR are \n");
for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    printf("%ld\n", EAR[i]);
}
getch();
}
```

the result is :

```
The elements of OAR are
5
7
1995706722

The elements of EAR are
2
4
```

Comment: Sounds like it's time to do some debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
for (i = 0; i <ARR[i]; i++)  
                 ^ Wrong  condition
```

to

```
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
```

And initialize the array `OAR` and `EAR` to `0`:

```
long int OAR[10] = {0}, EAR[10] = {0};
```

Comment: now the ans is 



    `The elements of OAR are
    5
    7
    9
    1930.....

    The elements of EAR are
    2
    4
    8`

Comment: done my problem was i put ' %ld ' instance of ' %d ' thank you :p

Comment: No. Problem was not `ld`. See the edit.